# Dealing with constructors in Java

Tags: java

I am still learning Java and have recently started getting exposure to some programming terms.

Yesterday my leader told me this,

For all of the assignments like this,

```
data.setTemp_c(obs.getCurrentWeather().getTempC());
data.setTemp_f(obs.getCurrentWeather().getTempF());
```

Can you move this to the constructor of the respective class so it's not cluttering up the Main loop?

What I am doing in the program was parsing the JSON response and storing in the database using Hibernate.

Though I got an idea that it had to do constructor of that class but didn't get what he wanted me to do. Can somebody help me in this?

Comment: Can you please clean up your question because it is not clear what have you tried and what are those method calls referring to.

Comment: What type is `data`?  do you have a `WeatherData` or something similar?  If so, please post that as well.

Answer (score 5):

The teacher wants you to have a constructor for `data` that takes `obs` as the parameter:

```
public Data(Obs obs) {
  final Weather currentWeather = obs.getCurrentWeather();
  setTemp_c(currentWeather.getTempC());
  setTemp_f(currentWeather.getTempF());
}
```

Then, in your main loop, you just say `new Data(obs);`